# Integer-handling alg0rithms

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

anyone has a good reference (books, websites) on optimised algorithms for integer handling - i am thinking about factorisation, primality, and number-theoretical function related problems.

Optimised here is intended in terms of computational complexity, which should be optimal for the problems (considering that, in avg., many of these problems have exponential complexity, optimisation is very important...).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this book](http://www.shoup.net/ntb/), by Victor Shoup, who is also the author of [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/), a library of algorithms for number theory. The bibliography [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_number_theory) is also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Digging a little bit on the Internet, I have found this wonderful resource:

https://gmplib.org

Synopsis taken from the GNU MP Manual:

> GNU MP is a portable library written in C for arbitrary precision arithmetic on integers, rational numbers, and floating-point numbers. It aims to provide the fastest possible arithmetic for all applications that need higher precision than is directly supported by the basic C types.

For myself is ok, since I usually write in C. However, translating these routines is not too hard.

Comment: GMP is good for basic arithmetic operations, but the OP asks for number theoretic algorithms. So even if they would probably *use* GMP, this library alone is off-topic.

Comment: In my opinion, the biggest shortcoming may be the computational complexity, instead...

Comment: I agree, but in practice both may be important. I remember implementing Lucas-Lehmer test in Python: with "standard" Python numbers, it was much slower than with gmpy (which uses GMP). And by [replacing division with shifts](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Talk:Lucas-Lehmer_test#Speeding_things_up), it was of course much faster in both implementations.

Comment: Sure bitwise operations are faster than arithmetical ones... but this is still heuristic optimisation, not computational.